# Is invocation some times Array.Copy more efficent than one loop?

Tags: c#, collections

Question is about constructor of List

```
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
```

Code of this constructor

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.List`1"/> class that contains elements copied from the specified collection and has sufficient capacity to accommodate the number of elements copied.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection">The collection whose elements are copied to the new list.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="collection"/> is null.</exception>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
      if (collection == null)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
      ICollection<T> collection1 = collection as ICollection<T>;
      if (collection1 != null)
      {
        int count = collection1.Count;
        if (count == 0)
        {
          this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
        }
        else
        {
          this._items = new T[count];
          collection1.CopyTo(this._items, 0);
          this._size = count;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        this._size = 0;
        this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
        foreach (T obj in collection)
          this.Add(obj);
      }
    }
```

I'm curious with case when collection is not ICollection. In this case instead iteration trough the collection and calculate count of element there is used Add method of List. On adding each time when capacity of list is not enough copying occurs by Array.Copy. It occurs before adding 5-th, 9-th, 17-th and so on element (multiple of 2 since 4).
I'm discouraged. Is invocation some times Array.Copy more efficent than one loop and then one copying?

Also below I add code of Add method and related method EnsureCapacity and fields of List Capacity

```
    public void Add(T item)
    {
      if (this._size == this._items.Length)
        this.EnsureCapacity(this._size + 1);
      this._items[this._size++] = item;
      ++this._version;
    }

    private void EnsureCapacity(int min)
    {
      if (this._items.Length >= min)
        return;
      int num = this._items.Length == 0 ? 4 : this._items.Length * 2;
      if ((uint) num > 2146435071U)
        num = 2146435071;
      if (num < min)
        num = min;
      this.Capacity = num;
    }

    public int Capacity
    {
      [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries"), __DynamicallyInvokable] get
      {
        return this._items.Length;
      }
      [__DynamicallyInvokable] set
      {
        if (value < this._size)
          ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.value, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_SmallCapacity);
        if (value == this._items.Length)
          return;
        if (value > 0)
        {
          T[] objArray = new T[value];
          if (this._size > 0)
            Array.Copy((Array) this._items, 0, (Array) objArray, 0, this._size);
          this._items = objArray;
        }
        else
          this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
      }
    }
```

Comment: The sequence can be one-time enumerable. Imagine an iterator method, which wraps data reader.

Comment: One-time enumerable in this case seems to me wrong implement IEnumerable, because we are not able to use Reset() method that is included to interface.

Comment: You're wrong. "The Reset method is provided for COM interoperability. It does not necessarily need to be implemented; instead, the implementer can simply throw a NotSupportedException."

Comment: Where did you get this information, can you give link to documentation maybe?

Comment: The documentation for that method is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't about efficiency.

Since the nature of `IEnumerable<T>` is unknown (it isn't an `ICollection<T>` implementation in this case), than `foreach` is the only safe way to perform copying items from `IEnumerable<T>` to the `List<T>`:

```
    static IEnumerable<string> GetSomeData()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("select name from some_table", connection))
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                yield return reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

`GetSomeData` can be iterated only once, and since `List<T>` constructor uses `Add`, it works. With your modifications, client code will face with an exception at this line:

```
        var list = new List<string>(GetSomeData());
```

Note, that one-time implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` is a normal thing. From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The Reset method is provided for COM interoperability. It does not
>   necessarily need to be implemented; instead, the implementer can
>   simply throw a NotSupportedException.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know about this and I was surprised when I saw implementation of ToList method.